# Is there any method or plugin that implement split long double quoted sentences?

Tags: vim

Assume that we have this long strings in codes.

```
strs = "Small is beautiful. Make each program do one thing well. Build a prototype as soon as possible. Choose portability over efficiency. Store data in flat text files. Use software leverage to your advantage.Use shell scripts to increase leverage and portability.Avoid captive user interfaces.Make every program a filter.";
```

And I want to split above sentences for readablity.

```
strs = "Small is beautiful." +
       "Make each program do one thing well." +
       "Build a prototype as soon as possible." + 
       "Choose portability over efficiency." +
       "Store data in flat text files." +
       "Use software leverage to your advantage." +
       "Use shell scripts to increase leverage and portability." +
       "Avoid captive user interfaces.Make every program a filter."
```

Is there any way for implemented this naturally?    It's boring repetive task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not trivial, probably. Boring and repetitive? Are we using the same editor? :)

```
f"s<CR><Esc>                    " Find the quote, replace with newline
$,C<CR><Esc>                    " remove the last quote so it's not in the way
km'                             " go down to the first line and set a jump mark
:s/\. \?/&<C-V><Enter>/g<CR>    " split into sentences
kV''                            " select all the sentences by jumping to our mark
:s/.*/"&" +/<CR>                " surround them with quotes, add the plus sign
$xx                             " the last one won't need a plus sign
gv>.                            " select the sentences again, and indent them twice
kJ                              " join the variable declaration
```

This is a pretty well-defined series of actions that you can save in a macro (e.g. `qz` to start recording, `q` to stop recording) and then play back at any other place that needs the same treatment (`@z`).

Comment: I feel like this _is_ trivial :) Note that while you answered the question perfectly, this does eat the space separating sentences which might result in a different string (this problem is in the question itself). I'm thinking of a regex only solution.

Comment: @sidyll: It does not eat spaces for me. Dot and optional space get reinserted back into the text via `&`. What makes you think it does? (and yes, it is trivial for someone who uses Vim for a bunch of years, but not necessarily for someone who is not used to full Vim potential.)

Comment: My lack of glasses and attention while reading. I’m very sorry. I shall delete the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Basically all you  have to do is to insert  a `" +\n"` after
every  period,  not followed  by  a  quote (to  protect  the
last  one). This  can easily  be done  in a  single command,
considering your cursor is on that line:

```
:s/\v\.\s*"@!\zs/" +\r"/g
```

Note that  this command  will also conserve  your occasional
whitespace  after   the  period.   In  your   question,  you
completely  removed  them. It  is  unclear  whether this  is
desired or not,  but it seems to modify  the final resulting
string.

One problem is  that this command does not take  care of the
indentation. Of  course it can  be solved easily with  a few
standard manual commands. However it  is also possible to do
it in the `:s` command using the following strategy:

- Get the line currently being worked on with `getline('.')`
- Match the content before the first quote with `matchstr(<line>, '[^"]*')`
- Get the length of what was matched, using `strlen(<match>)`
- Repeat a space character for that length with `repeat(' ', <length>)`
- Insert those spaces before the final `"` in the earlier `" +\r"`
  replacement

All in one (lengthy):

```
:s/\v\.\s*"@!\zs/\="\" +\n".repeat(' ',strlen(matchstr(getline('.'),'[^"]*'))).'"'/g
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a fully automated solution, but the scheme is simple and can be adapted to many similar cases:

```
" 1. Search
/\.\s*                  " find all sentence ends and go to the first of them

" 2. Start recording
qa                      " start recording macro a

" 3. Edit
dw                      " delete till begin of sentence
i                       " insert mode
." +<CR><TAB><ESC>      " insert ." +<CR><TAB> and return to normal mode

" 4. Goto next occurrence
n                       " goto next sentence

" 5. End recording
q                       " end of macro recording

" 6. Repeat
@a                      " repeat macro 1 time
3@a                     " repeat macro 3 times (or replace 3 with a bigger number)
```

or, maybe simpler to type and remember:

```
" 1. Search
/\.\s*                  " find all sentence ends and go to the first of them

" 2. Edit
caw                     " delete till begin of sentence and switch to insert mode
." +<CR><TAB><ESC>      " insert ." +<CR><TAB> and return to normal mode

" 3. Goto next occurrence and repeat the last change
n.                      " goto next sentence and repeat the last change
" Repeat 3. as many times as needed
```